# Gif Graph API Facebook

Tags: facebook, gif

I'm trying to do a post similar to those of Giphy with gif loop. To begin using the Graph API Explorer, I tried to post a gif using the "source field" but the results as is unsatisfactory

Comment: Facebook doesn’t allow you to upload animated GIFs.

Comment: It's possible. I can post gif if I set "href": "http://i.imgur.com/D8cdFqP.gif". But if I click on post from facebook I go to  http://i.imgur.com/D8cdFqP.gif. But I want go to http://i.imgur.com/D8cdFqP. If I set  "href": "http://i.imgur.com/D8cdFqP"  I get just article post without animated gif. Imgur and giphy handle it somehow. I mean they post "http://i.imgur.com/D8cdFqP.gif"  but redirect to "http://i.imgur.com/D8cdFqP"

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the link to the GIF it self:

```
FB.ui({ method:'share', href:'http://i.giphy.com/Kr4qE2Lm769HO.gif'});
```

Try to share this url http://i.giphy.com/Kr4qE2Lm769HO.gif in your fb timeline and you will see how it works.

Comment: i am trying to upload gif files from my blog to my facebook page. if i try to copy/paste your gif url, the gif can be playeble. what is special about giphy.com? when i try to share "http://bestgifever.com/data/images/2015/11/a355d1b5f5018b686c4a3cd637061ec0.gif" this url can not be playable at facebook. i don't get it.

Comment: Your URL has a double quote at the end. if you delete it, you would have no problems, I just try it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP videos for GIF and it's working perfect

```
$linkData = [
    'message' => $gifyTitle,
    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload($fileName)
];      
$response = $fb->post('/me/videos', $linkData,$pageAccessToken);
```